# I configured security authentication in hive，but why not use the user name and password can also access the database?

Tags: authentication, hive, beeline

I configured security authentication in hive, I modified

```
Enable Authorization   = true 
hive_security_authorization = SQLStdAuth
hive.users.in.admin.role
hive.security.authorization.createtable.owner.grants=ALL
hive.security.authorization.enabled=true
hive.metastore.authorization.storage.checks = true
hive.server2.enable.doAs=true
```

and I can use beeline connect jdbc:hive2://hdp1-nn02:10000/default with user and password, but I can access database without user and password use beeline connect `jdbc:hive2://`. I know that `jdbc:hive2://` is embed mode, but Why the embedded mode does not authorization? or How do I turn off the embedded mode？